# Bose Soundlink Mini II - how do I output high-quality sound?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, bluetooth, alsa, bluetooth-speaker

I have a Bose Soundlink Mini that works well - I can pair it with Kubuntu (14.10) and set it as an audio playback device for videos in Phonon. Sounds great. :)

Just purchased a Soundlink Mini II and I've now run into trouble. The speaker does not seem to be using the same high-quality audio mode via bluetooth. It sounds pretty bad. Here's an extract from

```
$ pacmd list-sinks
```

index 1 is the new Soundlink Mini II

index 2 is my old Soundlink Mini

```
index: 1
    name: <bluez_sink.08_DF_1F_43_F9_CD>
    driver: <module-bluetooth-device.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_VOLUME_CTRL LATENCY 
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 9530
    volume: 0: 100%
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
    volume steps: 16
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 1
    sample spec: s16le 1ch 8000Hz
    channel map: mono
                 Mono
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 128.00 ms
    card: 1 <bluez_card.08_DF_1F_43_F9_CD>
    module: 25
    properties:
            bluetooth.protocol = "hsp"
            device.intended_roles = "phone"
            device.description = "Bose Mini II SoundLink"
            device.string = "08:DF:1F:43:F9:CD"
            device.api = "bluez"
            device.class = "sound"
            device.bus = "bluetooth"
            device.form_factor = "speaker"
            bluez.path = "/org/bluez/502/hci0/dev_08_DF_1F_43_F9_CD"
            bluez.class = "0x240414"
            bluez.name = "Bose Mini II SoundLink"
            device.icon_name = "audio-speakers-bluetooth"
    ports:
            speaker-output: Speaker (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
                    properties:

    active port: <speaker-output>
index: 2
    name: <bluez_sink.00_0C_8A_B7_79_F2>
    driver: <module-bluetooth-device.c>
    flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: 
    priority: 9030
    volume: 0:  80% 1:  80%
            0: -5.81 dB 1: -5.81 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 100%
                 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 65.06 ms
    max request: 3 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 3
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    fixed latency: 45.32 ms
    card: 2 <bluez_card.00_0C_8A_B7_79_F2>
    module: 27
    properties:
            bluetooth.protocol = "a2dp"
            device.description = "Bose Mini SoundLink"
            device.string = "00:0C:8A:B7:79:F2"
            device.api = "bluez"
            device.class = "sound"
            device.bus = "bluetooth"
            device.form_factor = "hifi"
            bluez.path = "/org/bluez/502/hci0/dev_00_0C_8A_B7_79_F2"
            bluez.class = "0x240428"
            bluez.name = "Bose Mini SoundLink"
            device.icon_name = "audio-card-bluetooth"
    ports:
            hifi-output: HiFi (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
                    properties:

    active port: <hifi-output>
```

As you can see the sample spec for the new speaker is only mono @ 8kHz. :(

Does this mean I need to set pulseaudio to use A2DP for this device? How do I do this? I'm happy to edit config files but I'm lost as to where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: 14.10 is likely no longer supported as 15.04 should be available.  However you should be able to go into sound settings with the headset paired and switch to A2DP audio as it appears you are likely using HSP/HFP

Comment: Didn't switch to 15.04 due to numerous issues, might just wait for 15.10 :D But I found the settings for this in Phonon (I can select HSP or A2DP)  - however, even though I can select A2DP, it does not 'stick' - keeps reverting back to HSP. Also, icon for this new speaker looks different from the original speaker. Do I need to create some sort of profile file for this new speaker? Something to let the OS know what capabilities this speaker has? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same problem with my bose soundlink mini 2 in Ubuntu 14.04
The problem was solved when I installed BlueDevil program and connected to bose using it. After connection established you need to open sound settings and there you will be able to chsnge to A2DP profile ;-)
Hope it will help, because I am not a computer guru.
Good luck!